# Finding mysterious padding in my movingboxes div

Tags: html, find, padding

I have a movingboxes jquery plugin on my web site, and the left side of the panels in the box are shifted over approx 40px.

I suspect this has something to do with my stylesheet padding something but I can't seem to find it.  Can anyone explain what is shifting this over?

My site is [www.generationd.com](http://www.generationd.com) and the movingboxes is found at Products | High Availability Asterisk, then click Screen Shots tab.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you used [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firebug/) for Firefox?  If you're into web development, it's definitely worth checking out - among many, many other things, it'll let you see all the CSS styles calculated for a HTML element, and which CSS rules they're loaded from.  Should be just the thing for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the weird space on the left of the screenshots slider thingy, the offending css seems to be:

```
.mb-scrollContainer, .mb-scroll {
    width: 830px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    left: -35px;
    top: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

It's a bit half assed as i changed the width to acomodate pretty much the width of your slider thingy, and had to move it 35px to the left.

It may take a bit more work, but at least you have an idea of where the problem is.